# Python JSON loads error: ValueError: Extra data

Tags: python, json

## I have a list of dictionaries that I dump and output to file:

```
output = call_the_articles() #Function Outputs a List of Dicts
outfile = open("commentData.json", "w") #Also tried 'with open() as outfile:' form
data = dumps(output)
outfile.write(data)
outfile.close()
```

### But I can't use `json.loads()` to read the file, so either I'm encoding or decoding improperly(?) Example:

```
file = open("commentData.json", "r")
json_data = json.loads(file.read())
```

Returns:

```
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 28779 - line 1 column 69744 (char 28779 - 69744)
```

How should I store the list of dicts to file such that they can be decoded into JSON?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [json python doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#module-json)

> If the contents of fp are encoded with an ASCII based encoding other
>   than UTF-8 (e.g. latin-1),   then an appropriate encoding name must be
>   specified. Encodings that are not ASCII based (such as     UCS-2) are
>   not allowed, and should be wrapped with
>   codecs.getreader(encoding)(fp), or simply       decoded to a unicode
>   object and passed to loads().

Try to specify in the argument list for load the same encoding used in `CommendData.json`.